# How long can I be out of the US on a TN (NAFTA) visa?

Tags: usa, canada, immigration, visa

Due to the spread of the coronavirus my organization is recommending (essentially mandating) that all employees work from home (WFH) until further notice. I was planning on traveling to Canada from NYC until the WFH policy is lifted.

I have no reason to expect that I was exposed, and would like to stay in Canada with my family for as long as possible.

**Since I am working in the USA on a TN visa, is there a maximum amount of time I can spend outside of the USA?**

This [site](https://www.temple.edu/isss/international/TravelAndReentryWhileHoldingTNStatus.htm?fbclid=IwAR1yHStEimqDDigTEcKCt6mvYWUDiESPEBdwuB04zR6E3ul2qOhSmMhzO-A) seems to suggest that if my I-94 is not expired on return I will be fine.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the T in TN stands for treaty or perhaps trade, since a worker who lives in another country even temporarily is not generally considered a "traveler."  In any event, it does not matter what the T stands for, so ice edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no limit.  Even if you try to return after the expiration of your I-94, you can just reapply for admission as you did the first time you entered in TN status.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, it puts me at ease. Is there any source I could refer to for this?

Comment: @Shayan I'm pretty sure there's something in the regulations, but they're a little complicated so I didn't have time to read them in depth.  I'll add a link in the next few hours.

Comment: @Shayaan as explained in the source you linked in your answer, there are basically three scenarios: you have your I-94 and it's not expired (in that case, they let you in without further paperwork), you lost your I-94 but it's not expired (you have to show documentation for them to look it up), or, your I-94 is expired because it's been three years since initial entry. After three years are up, whether inside or out, TNs must file paperwork to continue their status.
It wouldn't be a case of you "having been gone too long" it would just be a case of the three year period of admission being up